# Label поверх Canvas с событиями

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется Canvas и на нём Label. На канвасе и лейбле имеются события нажатия ЛКМ. при нажатии на лейбл генерится также события и на канвасе, чего мне не нужно (мне нужно, чтобы событие на канвасе происходило только при нажатии на пустом месте). Есть ли какой-то стандартный способ сделать лейбл непрозрачным для нажатия кнопки мыши, чтоб не городить кучу кода?

Comment: в принципе такое может случиться, если на форме отрисовать сначала `Convas`, а потом `Label`.  Может стоит всё отрисовывать по средствам `Convas`?

Answer (score 7):

Попробуйте в обработчике события для `Label` написать

```
// это обработчик нажатия на Label
void OnLabelLeftMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // обработка
    e.Handled = true; // запретить дальнейшую обработку
}
```

---

Пояснение: данное событие, [хотя и не обладает всплывающей стратегией](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttondown(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) туннелирования, вызывается для контролов вверх по визуальному дереву. Устанавливая флаг, что событие обработано, мы предотвращаем его «всплытие». Точнее, событие будет всё ещё доставляться подписчикам, которые подписались через [`AddHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598899(v=vs.110).aspx), указав `handledEventsToo: true`, но только им.

Comment: о да, спасибо, помогло!

Comment: @DmitryLeechman: Пожалуйста!